# MP4 video remains hidden on mobile Flex app

Tags: apache-flex, video, flash-builder, flex-mobile, osmf

I'm currently struggling on my Flex mobile project using video player.
Basically, the problem is that I don't seem to be able to play, or at least see, .MP4 videos at all (no video, no sound, the player view is simply empty) on a iOS mobile device. As soon as I replace the source with a .FLV video, everything is working perfectly.

I have tried two approaches, even though they are using the same components underneath from what I've understood.

- OSMF: using VideoElement, MediaPlayer, MediaContainer and MediaPlayerSprite.

  ```
      private var media:VideoElement;
      private var mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer;
      private var mediaContainer:MediaContainer;
      private var mediaSprite:MediaPlayerSprite;


      protected function onViewCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
      {
          media = new VideoElement(new URLResource("http://10.140.1.165/jobs/92/eproofing/in/pages/versions/1/page1/video.mp4"));
          mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
          mediaContainer = new MediaContainer();
          mediaContainer.addMediaElement(media);
          mediaSprite = new MediaPlayerSprite(mediaPlayer, mediaContainer);
          mediaSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onVideoSpriteClicked, false, 0, true);
          mediaSprite.mediaPlayer.addEventListener(TimeEvent.CURRENT_TIME_CHANGE, onVideoTimeChanged);

          videoContainer.height = manager.selectedPage.formatHeight;
          videoContainer.width = manager.selectedPage.formatWidth;
          videoContainer.addChild(mediaSprite);
      }
  ```
- StageVideo: using Video, NetConnection and NetStream (StageVideo object usage is actually not yet implemented in the following code, this will be the next step)

  ```
      private var video:Video;
      private var ns:NetStream;
      private var nc:NetConnection;

      private var isVideoPlaying:Boolean = false;


      protected function onViewCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
      {
          video = new Video();
          nc = new NetConnection();
          nc.connect(null);
          ns = new NetStream(nc);
          ns.client = {onMetaData:onMetaData};

          ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onVideoLoaded);
          ns.play("http://10.140.1.165/jobs/92/eproofing/in/pages/versions/1/page1/video.mp4");
          this.isVideoPlaying = true;
      }

      private function onVideoLoaded(event:NetStatusEvent):void
      {
          video.attachNetStream(ns);
          videoContainer.addChild(video);

          videoContainer.height = video.height = video.videoHeight;
          videoContainer.width = video.width = video.videoWidth;
      }

      private function onMetaData(o:Object):void
      {

      }
  ```

Both gave me the same result: **the video appears and is played correctly as long as I'm using .FLV, I can't see/hear anything as soon as I'm loading a .MP4 video instead**
And of course, MP4 is the format I want to use for this project. I might add that I'm using H.264 codec for these .MP4 files.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

**Note that both formats are working as long as I'm using the emulator, the .MP4 issue is only occurring when I deploy the app on my iPad.**

This is a mobile **Flex 4.6** project, using **AIR 3.9** on **Flash Builder 4.7** for **Windows 7 Pro**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H.264 video is not supported on iOS devices with RTMP, and I've not seen it work without using the HTTP Live Streaming protocol.  Here's a section from the ActionScript reference for NetStream.play:

Special considerations for H.264 video in AIR 3.0 for iOS

```
For H.264 video, the iOS APIs for video playback accept only a URL to a file or
stream. You cannot pass in a buffer of H264 video data to be decoded. Depending
on your video source, pass the appropriate argument to NetStream.play() as
follows:   

- For progressive playback: Pass the URL of the file (local or remote).

- For streaming video: Pass the URL of a playlist in Apple's HTTP Live Streaming
(HLS) format. This file can be hosted by any server; Flash Media Server 4.5 and
higher has the advantage of being able to encode streams in HLS format.
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'm not sure to fully understand the difference between passing a file URL and a video buffer, but I definitely need to do a bit more research on that point. I'm going to see if I can use another encoding for this project if there is no other answers.

Comment: Have You Got Any solution?? I Have Same Issue.

Comment: The format for passing in the URL is the same, it's just that for streaming video you need a HLS format video (with an .m3u8 suffix, a playlist file for the stream contents).  Hard to follow, but examples are on https://developer.apple.com/streaming/, with some playable stream examples at https://developer.apple.com/streaming/examples/basic-stream.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy, but IF you really want H264 over RTMP on iOS, you could add a ANE controlling an iOS RTMP Video Playing App(native). There are some small companies that make RTMP H264 Video players for iOS.